# How to find the most popular subject - Django search

Tags: python, django, search

I am creating an application in Django in which students will review colleges. I need to find the 5 most popular subjects being discussed in ratings.  Have not been able to figure out how to do it.

My rating class is

```
class  Rating(models.Model): 
    rater=models.ForeignKey(Student)
    ratee=models.ForeignKey(College)
    skill=models.ForeignKey(Subj, default=1)
    rating_7=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    review_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    review_time=models.DateTimeField()
    likes=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Please suggest a way to implement the same.

Comment: The most popular subject is determined by which fields? By `rating_7`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `rating_7` and `likes` determine subject's popularity, then this query should help you:

```
Rating.objects.order_by('rating_7', 'likes')[:5]
```

Read more about [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but I know this. Actually I did not frame question very well but now after days of study, i have the solution. Appreciate your time though.